# Get data from json time and format time in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have list array of data times in json from website so i need convert time from 24 hours system to 12 hours and use times to make Compared with current time

this my code :-

```
 let task=URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, err) in
        if err != nil{
         print("err")
        }else{
            do{
               let dataT=try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                if let prayTime = dataT?["times"] as? NSArray  {
                    if let fajerTT = prayTime[0] as? String {         
                      let timeFormat = DateFormatter()
                       timeFormat.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
                        let timeFajer=timeFormat.date(from: fajerTT)
                      print(fajerTT)
                       print("\(timeFajer))")
                   self.fajerT.text=timeFajer
                    }else {print("false")}
                 }

            }catch{print("Error")

                  }


             }
    }



    task.resume()
```

and this from json

```
["05:05","06:30","12:56","16:30","19:21","19:21","20:51"]}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xcode swift am/pm time to 24 hour format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321947/xcode-swift-am-pm-time-to-24-hour-format)

Comment: And in addition: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36096533/1804251

Comment: Please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360941/convert-an-array-of-times-from-24hr-to-12-hr-in-swift

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare the times in the received array with the current time you don't need to convert the dates to 12 hour format.

Get the date components and compare it with the current date.

Basically your date format is wrong. Since the times are in 24 hour format it's `HH:mm`.

Example

```
let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
outputFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
let calendar = Calendar.current
let now = Date()

let times = ["05:05","06:30","12:56","16:30","19:21","19:21","20:51"]
for time in times {
    let date = timeFormatter.date(from: time)!
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)
    let match = calendar.date(now, matchesComponents: components)
    print(match)
    let output = outputFormatter.string(from: date)
    print(output)
}
```

And – as usual – do not use Foundation collection types (`NSArray`/`NSDictionary`) in Swift, use native types and never pass the option `.mutableContainers`

```
   if let dataT = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:Any],
      let prayTime = dataT["times"] as? [[String:Any]]  {
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i need to convert to 12 hours because i need use to put in ui for user